# ASP.NET MVC switching between secure to none secure content

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, https

After logging to the mvc site using a secure connection (https), calling actions using  https connection show up with the user logged in but calling actions using http it bahaves as if user didn't log on.

Since I need to use a virtual directory for https connections(and can't use that directory for http connection)
Https links start with:
**https**://www.sitename.com/**vdir**/...
Http links start with:
**http**://www.sitename.com/...

Any idea what's causing this behavior?

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different virtual directories cannot share session information in IIS 6, unless your are willing to use SQL State or a state server, and use the (unsafe?) cookieless session mode.

To accomplish the wanted behavior, open both port 80 and port 443 on the main site, so you can access them both with http://sitename.com and https://sitename.com. Then you can switch between http and https whenever you want. Just ditch the idea of different virtual directories for different protocols.

Comment: Thanks you! Since it was shared ssl (it's just a test site) I was forced to use a special virtual directory for the https connection.
Will this be fine when I use the same directory for both (opening  80 and 443 ports)? Do all subdirectories share session info?
According to the hosting company it's on IIS7, would that make a difference?

Comment: You will need to enforce session sharing in IIS 7 between VD's. It's possible afaik, but I've never used it myself. If you have one website with multiple ports this will work as expected. Multiple subdirectories will share the same session as long as they are in the same virtual directory/website.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find any prove for my earlier statement that this was possible in IIS 7. If anyone finds info on how to configure this, please add this to the answer :-)

Comment: Thank you Jan! In the real site we'll have our own certificate so that should be fine.